# Can we call C# resx in angular for localization?

Tags: c#, angular, localization

I have downloaded this application: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/localization/sample/3.x/Localization
to test the c sharp localization - change languages. It works perfectly fine.

The problem is that this application uses razor pages to get localized values. For instance everything
that needs to be localized is preceeded by the @Localizer.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">@Localizer["Dashboard"]</a></li>
        <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">@Localizer["Home"]</a></li>
        <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">@Localizer["About"]</a></li>
        <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">@Localizer["Contact"]</a></li>
    </ul>
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_LoginPartial")
</div>
```

I have to use the backend API but consume it in an angular pages. Does anyone know if this is feasible?

The values are actually stored in .resx files.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think it depends on the i18n framework you want to use to localise your angular app...

The angular default i18n package([`@angular/localize`](https://angular.io/guide/i18n)) uses [XLIFF-XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XLIFF) files to [store its translations](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#work-with-translation-files). `resx` files are XML too, so it should not be too difficult to convert your existing translations from `resx` to `xlf`, e.g. using an existing converter (like [ResxToXliff](https://github.com/StefanFabian/ResxToXliff)) or by just creating a custom XSLT to do the job.

If you are using an [i18next](https://www.i18next.com) based solution (like `angular-i18next`) on the other hand, then you could use the [`resx2i18next` utility](https://github.com/rolandpd/resx2i18next) to create i18next compatible JSON translation files. Or you could even create a new `i18next-resx` Backend, that uses the resx files directly.

I think it all depends on the specific needs of your project...

Comment: Thanks, I will check it and provide my feedback asap.